# Artifactory: Looking for Jars in the libs-release first then maven centrial

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, artifactory, repository

I am having some trouble with using Artifactory. The current way it is setup is it downloading the jars from the remote repositories and not downloading  the jars from my libs-release repo first.

Settings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.1.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <servers>
    <server>
  <username>admin</username>
  <id>central</id>
</server>
<server>
  <username>admin</username>
  <id>snapshots</id>
</server>
 </servers>
  <mirrors>
<mirror>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
  <name>remote-repos</name>
      <url>http://server:port/artifactory/remote-repos</url>
  <id>remote-repos</id>
</mirror>
</mirrors>
<profiles>
<profile>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>libs-release</name>
      <url>http://server:port/artifactory/libs-release</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <snapshots />
      <id>snapshots</id>
      <name>libs-snapshot</name>
      <url>http://server:port/artifactory/libs-snapshot</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>plugins-release</name>
      <url>http://server:port/artifactory/plugins-release</url>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
      <snapshots />
      <id>snapshots</id>
      <name>plugins-snapshot</name>
      <url>http://server:port/artifactory/plugins-snapshot</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
  <id>artifactory</id>
</profile>
 </profiles>
 <activeProfiles>
   <activeProfile>artifactory</activeProfile>
 </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

any insight on how to make it so it will download from my libs-release before going and looking for it on a remote repository would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

That's because you have the set up the `mirror`. Just remove it and your `libs-relese` will be in use.